# Rota Dinamica ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotas

Possuo dois Controllers: Faculdade e Curso

```
public class InstituicaoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Instituicao
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Instituicao(string instituicao) {

            return View();

        }

        public ActionResult Curso() {

            return View();
        }
    }


<a href="@Url.Action("Curso", "?", new {faculdade = "NomeFaculdade", curso = "Nomecurso"})">Detalhe do Curso </a>
```

Qual o procedimento para deixar dessa maneira: www.exemplo.com.br/{Nome Da faculdade Faculdade}/{Nome do Curso}

Comment: Na verdade você possui um Controller InstituicaoController que tem 3 métodos... A URL que você está querendo deveria executar qual metodo?

Answer (score 0):

Registre a seguinte rota em `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Instituicao",
            url: "{faculdade}/{curso}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Instituicao", action = "Instituicao", faculdade = "", curso = "" }
        );
```

Teremos que excluir `Instituicao` das rotas padrão porque a rota *Default* é gulosa e vai tentar resolver para `Instituicao` também. Implemente o seguinte atributo:

```
public class NotEqual : IRouteConstraint
{
    private string _match = String.Empty;

    public NotEqual(string match)
    {
        _match = match;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return String.Compare(values[parameterName].ToString(), _match, true) != 0;
    }
}
```

Modifique a rota *Default* para:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = new NotEqual("Instituicao") }
);
```